# Heat equation: Regularity of solution for initial conditions not in the domain but smooth

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, semigroup-of-operators

Consider the heat equation on the interval [0,1]

\begin{equation}
u_t = u_{xx}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u(0) = u_0 \in  H^2(0,1)
\end{equation}
with boundary conditions
\begin{equation}
u_{x}(0)=u_x(1)=0
\end{equation}

where $ H^2(0,1)$ is the space of twice weakly differentiable functions on $(0,1)$. If $(u_0)_x(0)=(u_0)(1)=0$ then $ \|u(\cdot,t)\|_{H^2(0,1)}$ is uniformly bounded for all $t\geq 0 $. However, **does a uniform bound also hold if $u_0$ does not satisfy the Neumann boundary condition but $u_0 \in  H^2(0,1)$?**

It seems to me that such a uniform bound should hold since we have that  $(\cdot)_{xx}$ with the Neumann BC generates a analytic semigroup, hence $\|u(\cdot,t)\|_{H^2(0,1)}$ is bounded for each $t > 0 $. Therefore, the only possibility is that $\|u(\cdot,t)\|_{H^2(0,1)}$ blows up near $t=0$. But we already know $\|u_0\|_{H^2(0,1)}$ is bounded. Hence,  $ \|u(\cdot,t)\|_{H^2(0,1)}$ is uniformly bounded for all $t\geq 0 $. Is this argument is right? otherwise what can go wrong?

Comment: It is clear that the evolution only "improves" second derivatives (in whatever sense you like) and the function itself (at least in $L^2$). Can it worsen first derivatives? If not then you're good. Thus the question seems to boil down to $\frac{d}{dt} \int_0^1 u_x^2 dx$...

Comment: Also, it would probably be a good exercise to write out what it means to be a weak solution of $u_t=u_{xx},u_x(0)=0,u_x(1)=0,u(0,x)=f(x)$ when $f_x(0)$ and/or $f_x(1)$ are not zero. Obviously there can be no strong solution to such a problem, so you should try to make sense of the weak solution to this problem. (I have dealt with a related problem where you are solving a heat equation with $u(0)=0,u(1)=0$ but the initial condition is $u(0,x)=1$.)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Out of curiosity, what is expected in the Dirichlet case you mentioned since in that case I would expect a sudden increase in the first derivative near t=0 due to the "near-discontinuity" at the boundaries? I was also confused about that case because my argument about the decrease in the $\|u\|_{H^2(0,1)}$ should also hold there, but intuitively this is not clear to me due to the initial mismatch at the boundaries.

Comment: So I misremembered, the actual problem I was dealing with had $u(t,0)=1,u(t,1)=0,u(0,x)=0$. Here $u(t,x)$ is the probability that a Brownian motion started at $x$ will hit $0$ before it hits $1$ and before a time amount of $t$ elapses. This has a *bona fide* discontinuity at $(t,x)=(0,0)$. Specifically, $u(0,0)$ is actually defined from the problem (it is $1$) but $\lim_{x \to 0^+} u(0,x)=0 \neq 1$. This causes a rapid change in the solution for small time near $x=0$.

Comment: However, in this case the solution that we obtain from "naive" separation of variables captures the behavior for $t>0$ correctly. That is, you can actually solve the problem I wrote in closed form.